# Can we user both <circuitBreaker> with <failover> in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I need to send messages to two back-end IBM MQs in a failover + round robin manner, but I found that if one IBM MQ failed, the camel will still try the failed endpoint for each inbound message, which slows down the whole process.

I try to combine the circuit breaker, but camel doesn’t allow to use  with .

How could I ask the camel not to try a failed endpoint for a particular period of time?

Answer (score 0):

with [error handler](https://camel.apache.org/error-handler.html) and [exception clause](https://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html)

for example (java DSL) let's assume you are wrapping the exception you want to handle in a `MyDelayedRetryableException`:

```
onException(MyDelayedRetryableException.class)
    .useOriginalMessage()
    .redeliveryDelay(1000) \\ wait 1 second before retry
    .backOffMultiplier(2.0) \\every retry wait last delay multiplied this value (1000, 2000, 4000,...)
    .maximumRedeliveries(100) \\ attempts before giving up
    .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
    .useExponentialBackOff();
```

The example above apply to all routes, you can also specify the error handling per route as well. There are multiple ways of doing what you are asking, for instance with the example above you can keep it general and use the `onExceptionOccurred` part to plug in some logic:

```
.onExceptionOccurred(
    exchange -> {
        //extra logic, like accessing the exchange headers
        log.error(exchange.getException() == null ? "no message" : exchange.getException().getMessage());
    }
)
```

see https://camel.apache.org/error-handling-in-camel.html for more info